# Changing value of DropDown menu in HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am doing some webs craping exercise. I want to get car sales figures in Europe and prepare some plots afterwards. 
Therefore I found http://carsalesbase.com/european-car-sales-data/ is a quite good data-source. 
I managed to get sales figures of one specific vehicle of one specific manufacturer. If I modify the URL, I can also access sales numbers of multiple cars and potentially multiple manufactureres.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

car_type=0
car_spec=['ford-focus','ford-fiesta','ford-ecosport']

my_url='http://carsalesbase.com/european-car-sales- 
data/ford/'+car_spec[car_type]+'/'

page = requests.get(my_url)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
t=soup.find("table")

rows=t.find_all('td')
```

E.g. I can access sales data of three ford vehicles.

However I want to iterate over every car of every manufacturer.
Carsalesbase has two dropdown menus for that purpose.
One is for the Manufacturer. I already managed to read all possibles values from that menu.
This is a "value / text" pair:

```
<option value="0">Select Brand</option>,
<option value="82"> Group</option>,
<option value="17">Alfa Romeo</option>,
<option value="1">Alpina</option>,
<option value="249">Alpine</option>,
<option value="2">Aston Martin</option>,
<option value="67">Audi</option>,
```

The second dropdown is for the car itself. This option only contains a default value as long as no car brand is selected in the first menu. Once you select the manufacturer in the first dropdown, the second one is populated with all cars of this manufacturer.
What I want to do is to programatically fill the first dropdown menu so that I can read out the second menu.

After that I believe I can access all the sales figures with this http-scheme:

http://carsalesbase.com/?hide-value=1&brand-option=17&model-option=2089&css-go=Go

I observed this with the chrome-developers tools in the network tab. Note that "brand-option=17" corresponds to Alfa Romeo which matches to my manual input.

I guess my missing link is just how to fill a dropdown menu programatically.

Can anyone help how to do that?

ps: I read about Selenium which seems a suitable tool for that but I don't like that the browser actually opens when you use it. there must be an easier way.

Thanks!

addition:

After some research I found you can probably do it with the requests package I am using anyway. This seems to be the relevant section in the html:

```
<form action="http://carsalesbase.com/" class="search-form" method="get" 
role="search">
<input class="" id="hide-value" name="hide-value" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<select class="kelas1" id="brand-option" name="brand-option">
<option value="0">Select Brand</option>
<option value="82"> Group</option> <option value="17">Alfa Romeo</option> 
<option value="1">Alpina</option> ... <option value="74">Volkswagen</option> 
<option value="26">Volvo</option>
</select>
<select class="kelas1" id="model-option" name="model-option">
<option value="0">Select Model</option>
</select>
<input name="css-go" type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

but still no idea how to fill that form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around to read table from html using pandas read_html. Just a few lines to pass table html into pandas DataFrame.

To me inspecting the responsive of 
http://carsalesbase.com/?hide-value=1&brand-option=17&model-option=2089&css-go=Go does not return a response.

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "http://carsalesbase.com/european-car-sales-data/alfa-romeo/"

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

tables = tree.xpath('//table')

for table in tables:
  df = pd.read_html(html.tostring(table), header=0)
  df = df[0]
  print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Prints below:

```
---+--------------+--------------------------+---------------+
|    |   Unnamed: 0 |   Alfa Romeo  All Models | MarketShare   |
|----+--------------+--------------------------+---------------|
|  0 |         2018 |                   83.438 | 0,00%         |
|  1 |         2017 |                   86.805 | 0,56%         |
|  2 |         2016 |                   66.155 | 0,44%         |
|  3 |         2015 |                   56.688 | 0,40%         |
|  4 |         2014 |                   58.976 | 0,46%         |
|  5 |         2013 |                   64.285 | 0,52%         |
|  6 |         2012 |                   90.145 | 0,72%         |
|  7 |         2011 |                  131.385 | 0,95%         |
|  8 |         2010 |                  110.654 | 0,79%         |
|  9 |         2009 |                  110.827 | 0,76%         |
| 10 |         2008 |                  102.183 | 0,71%         |
| 11 |         2007 |                  144.404 | 0,92%         |
| 12 |         2006 |                  145.171 | 0,93%         |
| 13 |         2005 |                  130.922 | 0,81%         |
| 14 |         2004 |                  158.195 | 0,98%         |
| 15 |         2003 |                  159.611 | 1,11%         |
| 16 |         2002 |                  169.82  | 1,16%         |
| 17 |         2001 |                  205.431 | 1,36%         |
| 18 |         2000 |                  176.389 | 1,17%         |
| 19 |         1999 |                  180.154 | 1,18%         |
| 20 |         1998 |                  172.675 | 1,19%         |
| 21 |         1997 |                  128.107 | 0,95%         |
| 22 |         1996 |                  117.543 | 0,92%         |
| 23 |         1995 |                  130.358 | 1,08%         |
| 24 |         1994 |                  101.548 | 0,85%         |
| 25 |         1993 |                  114.292 | 1,02%         |
| 26 |         1992 |                  156.184 | 1,16%         |
| 27 |         1991 |                  180.035 | 1,34%         |
| 28 |         1990 |                  203.787 | 1,51%         |
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is not that I cannot read out the table values. That works fine. Even if I set http://carsalesbase.com/?hide-value=1&brand-option=17&model-option=2089&css-go=Go  as url, I can parse it with Beatifulsoup and my sales graph comes out nicely. My issue is rather that I cannot readout "model-option" to iterate through all models of - let's say - Alfa Romeo (brand-option=17). This is becaus I cannot fill the brand-option drop down programatically. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to solve this. I saw that the second dropdown was populated by a Java Script. This script generated the possible entries of the second dropdown depending on what you chose in the first one.

However the data from the second dropdown was stored in another Java script on that website.

So I scraped all "script" tags in the HTML until I find the one containing the data I need. I can open that script programatically and transfer the data from inside the script to my main python script.

This way I can iterate through this http scheme:

http://carsalesbase.com/?hide-value=1&brand-option=17&model-option=2089&css-go=Go

This is a quite specialized solution and obviously you need selenium or comparable to scrape websites with JS in general. 
But for my problem this is sufficient.